# jQuery and ASP.NET Download File from Database

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have looked at many online resources and have built my script, but it still doesn't seem to give me the file.  It simply loads the page "client-home2.aspx/downloadAttachment" instead of executing the code and delivering the file.

Here is my code behind:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public void downloadAttachment(string id)
    {

        DbProviderFactory dbf = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory();
        using (IDbConnection con = dbf.CreateConnection())
        {
            string sSQL;
            sSQL = "select top 1                " + ControlChars.CrLf
                 + " FILENAME, FILE_MIME_TYPE, ATTACHMENT" + ControlChars.CrLf
                 + "  from vwATTACHMENTS_CONTENT" + ControlChars.CrLf
                 + " where 1 = 1                    " + ControlChars.CrLf;
            //Debug.Print(sSQL);
            using (IDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = sSQL;

                Sql.AppendParameter(cmd, id.ToString(), "ATTACHMENT_ID");

                cmd.CommandText += " order by DATE_ENTERED desc" + ControlChars.CrLf;

                using (DbDataAdapter da = dbf.CreateDataAdapter())
                {
                    ((IDbDataAdapter)da).SelectCommand = cmd;
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        da.Fill(dt);

                        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                        {

                            foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
                            {
                                string name = (string)r["FILENAME"];
                                string contentType = (string)r["FILE_MIME_TYPE"];
                                Byte[] data = (Byte[])r["ATTACHMENT"];

                                // Send the file to the browser
                                Response.AddHeader("Content-type", contentType);
                                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + name);
                                Response.BinaryWrite(data);
                                Response.Flush();
                                Response.End();
                            }

                        }
                        else
                        {

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
$('.attachmentLink').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    /*
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "client-home2.aspx/downloadAttachment",
    data: '{id:\'' + id + '\'}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
    //alert(msg.d);
    }
    });
    */
    $.download('client-home2.aspx/downloadAttachment', 'id=' + id);
    return false;
});
```

**I am using this function http://filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_plugin_for_requesting_ajax_like_file_downloads/**

The problem is, it never gives me the file; it just navigates to `client-home2.aspx/downloadAttachment`.

How can I resolve this issue so that I can download the file?

Thank you.

Comment: Any particular reason you are using jQuery to do this?

Comment: Can I avoid it?  I want the file to download on the click of the button.

Comment: You're not downloading one file: you're trying to download 20, with a single http request. That just won't work. Always two there are -- no more, no less: a request and a response.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I only want to download one file.  I can remove the loop.  I updated the code `select top 1`.

Comment: @ChristopherRayl I replaced the link with http://localhost/FACTS/Webforms/client-home2.aspx/downloadAttachment?id=9bfbcc76-a260-4b9c-88f1-54564321sdfds in order to circumvent using jQuery but it still doesn't deliver the file.

Comment: It doesn't even seem like it's calling my method.  When I put `Debug.Print("test");` on the first line of the method `downloadAttachment()`, it never shows in the output panel while debugging.

Comment: I think the issue is that I am not putting this in the page load.  I think the download function must be on a separate page and in the page load.  That is how I see all the other examples...  Gonna try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  I had to make a separate file because the headers were already being sent.  So, my separate file is called "downloadAttachment" and looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Xml;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;

namespace SplendidCRM.WebForms
{
    public partial class downloadAttachment : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        string HostedSite;
        protected DataView vwMain;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Sql.IsEmptyGuid(Security.USER_ID))
                Response.Redirect("~/Webforms/client-login.aspx");

            HostedSite = Sql.ToString(HttpContext.Current.Application["Config.hostedsite"]);

            string id = Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString();

            DbProviderFactory dbf = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory();
            using (IDbConnection con = dbf.CreateConnection())
            {
                string sSQL;
                sSQL = "select top 1                " + ControlChars.CrLf
                     + " FILENAME, FILE_MIME_TYPE, ATTACHMENT" + ControlChars.CrLf
                     + "  from vwATTACHMENTS_CONTENT" + ControlChars.CrLf
                     + " where 1 = 1                    " + ControlChars.CrLf;
                //Debug.Print(sSQL);
                using (IDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = sSQL;

                    Sql.AppendParameter(cmd, id.ToString(), "ATTACHMENT_ID");

                    cmd.CommandText += " order by DATE_ENTERED desc" + ControlChars.CrLf;

                    using (DbDataAdapter da = dbf.CreateDataAdapter())
                    {
                        ((IDbDataAdapter)da).SelectCommand = cmd;
                        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                        {
                            da.Fill(dt);

                            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                            {

                                foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
                                {
                                    string name = (string)r["FILENAME"];
                                    string contentType = (string)r["FILE_MIME_TYPE"];
                                    Byte[] data = (Byte[])r["ATTACHMENT"];

                                    // Send the file to the browser
                                    Response.AddHeader("Content-type", contentType);
                                    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + MakeValidFileName(name));
                                    Response.BinaryWrite(data);
                                    Response.Flush();
                                    Response.End();
                                }

                            }
                            else
                            {

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

        }

        public static string MakeValidFileName(string name)
        {
            string invalidChars = Regex.Escape(new string(System.IO.Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()));
            string invalidReStr = string.Format(@"[{0}]+", invalidChars);
            string replace = Regex.Replace(name, invalidReStr, "_").Replace(";", "").Replace(",", "");
            return replace;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can only send one HTTP response per WebMethod call. That means only one file at a time. Using `Response.End()` stops anything else from coming back to the web browser, and there's likely an exception thrown the 2nd time through the foreach loop. The only way around this is to call the WebMethod 20 times from your jQuery code, and have an argument to know which file to return each time if there is more than one result in the query. Even that might not work.

But I suspect you really intended that ID field to result in only one record. In that, case, you need to be aware to two things. The first is that the SqlCommand type resets it's Parameters collection when you change the `CommandText` property. Therefore, you need to finish creating the entire sql string text *before* adding your ID parameter. The second is that your ID parameter doesn't even matter right now, because *your sql code never references that parameter*.

I'm hesitant to post this code, because there are other things that are likely wrong as well, but this should be an improvement over what you have. Notice that I also ended up doing the same job, but with a *lot less code*:

```
[WebMethod]
public void downloadAttachment(string id)
{

    string SQL =
          "select top 1 FILENAME, FILE_MIME_TYPE, ATTACHMENT" + ControlChars.CrLf
        + "  FROM vwATTACHMENTS_CONTENT" + ControlChars.CrLf
        + " where ID = @ATTACHMENT_ID" + ControlChars.CrLf
        + " order by DATE_ENTERED desc";
    //Debug.Print(SQL);

    DbProviderFactory dbf = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory();
    using (IDbConnection con = dbf.CreateConnection())
    using (IDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = SQL;
        Sql.AppendParameter(cmd, id, "ATTACHMENT_ID");

        using (IDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (rdr.Read())
            {
                // Send the file to the browser
                Response.AddHeader("Content-type", r["FILE_MIME_TYPE"].ToString());
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + r["FILENAME"].ToString());

                Response.BinaryWrite((Byte[])r["ATTACHMENT"]);

                Response.Flush();
                Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, `Response.End()` should never be called directly. Instead, the correct would be `Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()`.

Comment: First of all, thanks for posting, but I have a syntax error on `cmd.ExecuteReader()` Error 94 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.IDataReader' to 'System.Data.Common.DbDataReader'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: I changed `DbDataReader rdr` to `IDataReader rdr` and it goes away, and I'm going to test it now...

Comment: Unfortunately, it still does not render the file.  It just opens the page with no stylesheets.

Comment: Maybe a Response.Clear() at the top of the if(){} block. Also, check that your query does return a record.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I've done it in the past, but I went about it differently:

View:

```
foreach (var file in foo.Uploads)
  {
      <tr>
        <td>@Html.ActionLink(file.Filename ?? "(no filename)", "Download", "Upload", new { id = file.UploadId }, null)</td>
      </tr>
  }
```

Code Behind in my UploadConroller:

```
public ActionResult Download(Guid id)
{
    var upload = this.GetUpload(id);
    if (upload == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return File(upload.Data, upload.ContentType, upload.Filename);
}


private Upload GetUpload(Guid id)
{
    return (from u in this.DB.Uploads
            where u.UploadId == id
            select u).SingleOrDefault();
}
```

Feel free to cargo cult this, it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: But then again, this answer fits for MVC/Razor rather than Web Forms.  My Bad.

Comment: I wish I was using MVC!  Never heard the term `cargo cult` either...   Just wikipedia'd it